# BI Tool(information builders vs oracle BI

Tags: oracle-bi

we are kind of in a ‘decision making situation’ to make a road map of our BI system.

I would like to hear experts opinion on Information Builders when compared to Oracle BI. I am working in Oracle BI but I dont have knowledge on Webfocus offered by Information Builders, so problably users who has knowledge on both sides, has a good overview on pros and cons.

Like to hear any opinion or suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I currently work with IBI products and their reporting language WebFocus 8.  This along with their new AppStudio development tool and BI Portal deployment platform.  If you like being forced to use a GUI to build your user-facing components, having no good access to the HTML, then go with IBI and WF.  Other than their having forced the developer to lose access to edit HTML, and tool generated code being horrid, it's a fairly good product.  Their new push for responsive design is still early in its implementation.  Lots of restrictions and good portions of their products rely on being both compatible with IE8 or used in IE.  Not much of a fan of IBI.